# What is the difference and relation between Hartree-Fock and Hartree-Fock-Bogoliubov?

Tags: condensed-matter, nuclear-physics, many-body, superfluidity, mean-field-theory

In nuclear physics literature, both appear very often.

HF is easy. It refers to a variational method with a Slater determinant variational wave function. What is HFB? Does it refer to a similar variational wave function which is annihilated by some quasi-particle annihilation operator? The quasi-particle annihilation operator is a mix of some common annihilation and creation operators.

Comment: Almost none of your questions has an [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer. Consider to accept one answer if possible or clarify if something is unclear/not answered with e.g. a comment under an answer or by editing the question.

Answer (score 2):

Its the extension of reorganizing the tensor product basis of the n-particle Hilbert space for fermions in the antisymmetric subspace by minimizing the 1-particle Hamiltonian sum. Bogoliubov adds the 2-particle attractive interaction known from superfluidity and BCS theory of superconductivity.

This is working of course numerically for small particle numbers only because the pair interaction increases with n^2.

Short explanation e.g.

[HFB approximation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.6081)